# Eclipse IDE variables, scope and storage

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse IDE presents a bewildering set of variables (e.g. build variables such as `${project_loc}`). Many are auto defined but you can create and edit your own and there are many places to do this.

However, creating a variable in one place often doesn't make it accessible in another and their scope is very opaque, leading to duplicates and multiple variables with different names but the same function. Furthermore, it is never clear whether a variable is associated with a project, the workspace, or something else.

e.g. in a cross compiled project I need to define the cross compiler prefix both in the overall project preferences, but again in all the debug/run configurations. Isn't there one place where I can define this where it will work in both?

e.g. Why is `${PROJECT_LOC}` (upper case) auto defined in '**Linked Resources**' but the variable referenced in a builder is called `${project_loc}`? can I reference one from the other? are they both in scope in the same places? Why do I have a configuration that references `${ProjDirPath}` to get the same result?

Can someone point me at documentation or a good post which gives an explanation the scope hierarchy of these variables and where they are stored?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why `${PROJECT_LOC}` is upper case in '**Linked Resources**' but the variable referenced in a builder is lower case `${project_loc}`. It baffles me, too.

All I found regarding variables used for external builders is this documentation:

https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_o_run.htm